# Add a QTreeView in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I would like to register a QTreeView c++ object to QML.
I tried to register it like this:

main.cpp:

```
qmlRegisterType<QTreeView>("com.MyApp.QTreeView", 1, 0, "QTreeView");
```

relevant code in main.qml

```
import com.MyApp.QTreeView 1.0

QWindow {
    QTreeView{
        headerHidden: true
    }
}
```

Result: it compiles. headerHidden property is found so it is registered correctly. However I have an error at runtime:
ASSERT: "!d->isWidget" in file kernel\qobject.cpp, line 2090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QWidgets are not directly compatible with QML such that they can be embedded in a QML view. They are two different UI technologies and cannot be used together in that fashion.

You can however embed a QML view inside of a QWidget hierarchy:

https://www.ics.com/blog/combining-qt-widgets-and-qml-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer

Or just use the QML TreeView component instead:

https://doc.qt.io/qttreeview/qml-treeview.html

Comment: Ok, How can I embed the QWidget in my QWindow after that ? Some code would be appreciate. I dont want to use TreeView because my QTreeView object is already setup the way I want

Comment: The simple answer is you can't.

Comment: Ok so your suggestion is to put my qml view in a container and then add it to a QMainWindow ui for example ?

Comment: That worked. it is actually even better like this